# alternative to mylockbox

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, usb-flash-drive, passwords

There's an app called my lockbox. I've seen it from cybernetnews and what it does is to hide/password protect a folder. The folder can only be seen if you launch the application and input the correct password.
Its basically not encrypting, which I like the most. 
But I've been having problem protecting the folders which are in my flash drive. The program is so dumb that it can only protect those that are in the computer. 
Do you know of any alternative?Except encrypting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for you?
[WinMend Folder](http://www.winmend.com/folder-hidden/)

> WinMend Folder Hidden is a free
>   file/folder hiding tool. While
>   ensuring the absolute system safety,
>   this application can quickly hide
>   files and folders on local partitions
>   and/or on **removable devices**